# Efficient recursive iterator: Possible?

Tags: python, performance, iterator

This has bothered me for a long time. I want an iterator over a binary tree (or similar nested structure) that's efficient, simple, and pythonic. For example for usages like these:

```
for value in values(root):
    do_something_with_value(value)

print(sum(values(root)))
```

Here `root` is the tree's root node, and nodes have a `.value`, `.left` and `.right`. And `values` is supposed to give me the desired iterator/iterable over the tree's values.

Let n be the number of nodes in the tree and h be the height of the tree.

#### Attempt 1: Too slow

```
def values(root):
    if root:
        yield from values(root.left)
        yield root.value
        yield from values(root.right)
```

Simple, pythonic, lazy, and takes only O(h) space. This *should* be it. But... it's stacked generators and every single value gets yielded through the entire stack of generators. So the whole iteration takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) time in the worst case and O(n log n) time even in the best case.

#### Attempt 2: Too complicated

```
def values(root):
    stack = []
    while root or stack:
        while root:
            stack.append(root)
            root = root.left
        root = stack.pop()
        yield root.value
        root = root.right
```

Iterative with a stack of nodes. Only takes O(h) space and O(n) time, but it's much more complicated than the above totally natural recursion.

#### Attempt 3: Too big

```
def values(root):
    result = []
    def collect_values(root):
        if root:
            collect_values(root.left)
            result.append(root.value)
            collect_values(root.right)
    collect_values(root)
    return result
```

This collects all values in a semi-global list. Natural recursion and O(n) time, but sadly O(n) space and isn't lazy.

#### Attempt 4: Can't get it to work

Instead of a semi-global list I thought maybe I could abuse a semi-global *generator*. As a sort of pipe from inside the recursion directly to the outside. The recursion would `send` values into it, and the outside could fetch them. Something like this:

```
def values(root):
    pipe = magic_generator_pipe()
    def iterate(root):
        if root:
            iterate(root.left)
            pipe.send(root.value)
            iterate(root.right)
    iterate(root)
    yield from pipe
```

But I can't get it to work and I'm not sure it's possible.

#### Attempt 5: Maybe

Something with `threading` or `asyncio`? One more idea I have is that the `values` function starts a new thread. This thread recursively iterates the tree and communicates the values to the main thread in the `values` function, which yields them to the original outside caller. And they lock each other appropriately. But I don't have much experience with this.

#### The question

Is there a way to achieve all I want?

1. Pythonic lazy iterator
2. O(n) total time
3. O(h) space
4. Natural recursion

So essentially I want something like Attempt 1, but fast. Because I've used recursive `yield from` for several problems and always feel bad about the time complexity.

To clarify: With "too complicated" I really meant the iterative algorithm (it's not that complicated, but compared to the natural recursion it is). A solution that's "complicated" only in a "technical" way (like with an extra thread or @chepner's trampoline idea) would still be interesting. I just insist on the natural recursion (or something similarly *algorithmically* simple) and the other three goals.

Comment: This might sound even *more* complicated, but the complicated part is at least isolated in a single, reusable piece. Write `values` as a tail-recursive function, then use a trampoline (for example, https://github.com/0x65/trampoline) to implement tail-call optimization. (Although, you would want the accumulator to be an iterator, rather than a list. I *think* that's possible, though I haven't thought it through. The cost of chaining together a bunch of single-item (or at least small) iterators might defeat the purpose of this approach.)

Comment: @chepner Hmm, can we do tail-recursion with my *two* recursive calls? About such extra stuff defeating the purpose: With my "too complicated" I really meant the iterative *algorithm* (it's not that bad, but compared to the natural recursion it is). A solution that's "complicated" only in a "technical" way (like with an extra thread or a trampoline) would still be interesting. I just insist on the natural recursion (or something similarly algorithmically simple) and the other three stated goals.

Comment: Hm. There's also https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/on-recursion-continuations-and-trampolines/, which explains how to use CPS to convert a natural implementation of Fibonacci numbers into a tail-recursive function, but sadly doesn't provide an actual implementation of the algorithm like my previous link. Maybe if you're up to writing the complicated part yourself... :)

Answer (score 2):

My approach may not satisfy you since it's an inversion of what you are doing, namely using a callback. You pass to a function that is able to iterate the structure a callback method to be invoked for each value encountered. In this example, function `walk` is called with `callback` function. In this case the structure is a tree that is walked and for each node value, the callback function is invoked.

```
def walk(root, callback):

    def tree_walk(node):
        if node['left']:
            tree_walk(node['left'])
        callback(node['value'])
        if node['right']:
            tree_walk(node['right'])

    tree_walk(root)


node4 = {'value': 4, 'left': None, 'right': None}
node3 = {'value': 3, 'left': node4, 'right': None}
node2 = {'value': 2, 'left': None, 'right': None}
node1 = {'value': 1, 'left': node2, 'right': node3}

def do_something_with_value(value):
    print('value:', value)

walk(node1, do_something_with_value)
```

Prints:

```
value: 2
value: 1
value: 4
value: 3
```

Comment: Right. I've actually done this before. Though it's indeed not really what I'm looking for. As stated I'd like an an iterator/iterable. So that I can use it as ubiquitously as other iterators. In my toy example, your way perfectly replaces the `for` loop. But what if the loop body is not just a function call with the value as the only argument, or if I want to use it in other ways like `sum(values(root))`? I don't see it work then, at least in the `sum` case.

Comment: Note: I edited the question to clarify what I mean, adding the `sum` example but keeping the `for`-loop example as it was so that your answer remains a perfect replacement for that case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. I managed to get a combination of attempts 4 and 5 working. I use a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) as a "pipe" between a thread traversing the tree and the main thread yielding the values to the caller:

```
def values(root):
    q = Queue(40)
    def dfs(root):
        if root:
            dfs(root.left)
            q.put(root.value)
            dfs(root.right)
    def go():
        dfs(root)
        q.put(stop)
    stop = object()
    Thread(target=go).start()
    while True:
        value = q.get()
        if value is stop:
            return
        yield value
```

Benchmark with a linear tree of 10000 nodes (every node only has a left child, so tree height is 10000):

```
4184 ms  attempt1_recursive_generator
   2 ms  attempt2_iterative
   9 ms  attempt3_build_list
  69 ms  attempt5_threading
```

So it's indeed much faster than the quadratic-time recursive generator, but also much slower than the iterative and list-builders solutions.

Note I allowed the queue to hold maxsize=40 values before switching the thread. With maxsize=1 it takes about 320 ms due to the overhead of constantly switching. At around maxsize=40, the overhead becomes insignificant.

So while it achieves what I wanted and shows that it's *possible*, I'm now interested in reducing the overhead further.

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVXbbtswDH3XV@ilqD1kRrJ2wFAgv1BgQN@GQnBj2tEmW4pEd8vXZ7rFllMncPXihDy8HZGUOuJedg8/lD6dai1binsNZcW7hvJWSY30xQuIVx566OGs@On@BDnyFjieFRXUZS@QOammpfFqTaLWHA0hO1EaQ59lBU@E2mNNKGO848hYZkDUK/peih5WVECN22fZ2Z@aN/vwOw9W7jhw4bF0G2ymKmdvNe4zVXhvVuO/hLgMSkRoFW6Yhl2vDX8H1kAHukSpMy0l5mO2PpRJpe7wmjrJKHDnyEFU1BOVWPnM8hmgV04rueHFpx/caMBed5PMJnV9YxxdMbauZdUYLHd/LEW/XgfR3z0X4FOkUgfAtNgRMJUP/opSKeiqmN8lxHve0oEgMqMMbpRU2SfoSx2HK19C2QN767momOAGl3Gmwdjen5Lm0DspBOyQzVtd7R13ZkxnmmcMnjIcmMgX@Uxa6QokT8r0xIWAi6j8zobVsozJgyXR75jscZ1PuKzqzxF4xl9h7VCoHm@yNTi4oMgl08jsIo8hPfIxikGp8mTApLJVyrffluikm8POzbDUDeC2kXlhe16niDBmL7qHaezzJjwU1vJiPnhkmnLjIz/N9I@7w5mhGudp9prrvtsZ1/MecmuNrlJEspAm8nTqJoqkh1bklRD7lhQGMMaRneAtx2yzWa9tx5A48u7BILXdVrF427Vl10DmUOt4dQO0giw@PLE0@Kfs3aRuXLHOiy86mOPaAvwrl51XcdwCfnE4ZKAqaHFE06/WmMTbibG48cHG6xlySMYNhEkQ9jUF@7aew26jidcrzTvM7u8eK9oaek/vaIb0C93AQ77yRRSMdWULjOWn038)):

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def attempt1_recursive_generator(root):
    def values(root):
        if root:
            yield from values(root.left)
            yield root.value
            yield from values(root.right)
    return values(root)

def attempt2_iterative(root):
    def values(root):
        stack = []
        while root or stack:
            while root:
                stack.append(root)
                root = root.left
            root = stack.pop()
            yield root.value
            root = root.right
    return values(root)

def attempt3_build_list(root):
    def values(root):
        result = []
        def collect_values(root):
            if root:
                collect_values(root.left)
                result.append(root.value)
                collect_values(root.right)
        collect_values(root)
        return result
    return values(root)

def attempt5_threading(root):
    def values(root):
        q = Queue(40)
        def dfs(root):
            if root:
                dfs(root.left)
                q.put(root.value)
                dfs(root.right)
        def go():
            dfs(root)
            q.put(stop)
        stop = object()
        Thread(target=go).start()
        while True:
            value = q.get()
            if value is stop:
                return
            yield value
    return values(root)

funcs = [
    attempt1_recursive_generator,
    attempt2_iterative,
    attempt3_build_list,
    attempt5_threading,
]

sys.setrecursionlimit(11000)

root = None
for value in range(10000):
    root = Node(value, root)

expect = None
for func in funcs:
    t0 = timer()
    result = list(func(root))
    t = timer() - t0
    if expect is None:
        expect = result
    else:
        assert result == expect
    print('%4d ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
```